# Regarding essential spectrum of the unilateral shift operator

Tags: operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

This is with context to Example 4.10 in Section 11 of the book : A course in functional Analysis by J.B Conway. Let $\sigma_{le}(S)$ and $\sigma_{re}(S)$ denote the left and right essential spectrum of the unilateral shift operator $S$ respectively. Let $\partial{\mathbb{D}}$ be the boundary of the open unit ball in the Complex plane.[image] I can understand in the example why 
$\partial{\mathbb{D}}\subseteq \sigma_{le}(S)\cap\sigma_{re}(S)$. And can prove that 
$\sigma_{le}(S)\cap\sigma_{re}(S)\subseteq\partial{\mathbb{D}} $. But I do not understand how $\partial{\mathbb{D}}=\sigma_{le}(S)=\sigma_{re}(S)$?
Can anyone explain how?

Comment: What is left  (right) spectrum ? Spectrum as the left (right) multiplication operator on the space of bounded operators ?

Comment: In Conway's book he defines the left (right) spectrum of an operator $a$ to be the set of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $a - z$ is not left (right) invertible. The spectrum is therefore the intersection of the left and right spectrum. I had never heard of it before, so I don't know how widely used this terminology is.

Comment: Does looking back at Proposition 4.3 of the same section help in showing that $\sigma_{le}(S) = \sigma_{re}(S)$?

Answer (score 1):

If $S(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ is the unilateral shift, it is easy to see that $S-\lambda I$ is bounded below for $|\lambda|<1$: $\|(S-\lambda I)x\| \geq \|Sx\|-\|\lambda x\|= (1-|\lambda|)\|x\|$.

And considering the adjoint operator $S^*(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots)$, it is easy to check that $\dim \ker(S^*-\lambda I)=1$ for $|\lambda|<1$.

Moreover $\dim\ell^2/Im(S-\lambda I)= \dim \ker(S^*-\lambda I)=1$ for $|\lambda|<1$, hence 
$S-\lambda I$ is a Fredhom operator with index equal to $-1$ for $|\lambda|<1$.

For $|\lambda|>1$, $S-\lambda I$ is invertible, hence a Fredhom operator with index equal to $0$.

The continuity of the index implies that $S-\lambda I$ is not a Fredhom operator for $|\lambda|=1$. This fact admits a direct proof by showing that for $|\lambda|=1$,  $S-\lambda I$ is injective but not bounded below.

Comment: This is a fine way to show that $\sigma_e(S) = \partial\mathbb{D}$ but I can't see how this shows that $\sigma_{le}(S) = \sigma_{re}(S)$.

Comment: If $\lambda$ were in $\sigma_{le}(S)\setminus\sigma_{re}(S)$, then $S-\lambda I$ would have infinite dimensional kernel, and closed, finite codimensional range. And this is no true for any $\lambda$.

Comment: Similarly,  $\lambda \in\sigma_{re}(S)\setminus\sigma_{le}(S)$ is not possible.

Comment: Antother argument: by the continuity of the index for semi-Fredholm operators, if both $\sigma_{le}(S)$ and $\sigma_{re}(S)$ have empty interior, they coincide.

Comment: Why does being injective and bound below imply that the map is not Fredholm?

Comment: @Sarah: Look at the definition of Fredholm operator in Wikipedia.

Comment: I have read the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator but could not find this property :( Where is it?

Comment: Being injective and bounded below DOES NOT imply that the map is not Fredholm; e.g., the identity operator.

Comment: Can I ask you @M.González why is the map invertible of $|\lambda| > 1$? I am trying to prove surjectivity but I am having trouble with it...

Comment: If $\|S\|=1$ and $|\lambda|>1$ then $S-\lambda I$ is invertible because the series $\lambda^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1} S)^k$ converges to an inverse of $S-\lambda I$.

Comment: Alternatively, if $|\lambda|>1$ then the conjugate operator $S^*-\lambda I$ is bounded below; hence $S-\lambda I$ is surjective.